# When I use jupyter notebook to pip install COVID19Py ,I get a ERROR Command errored out with exit status 1

Tags: python, jupyter

After I run this code in jupyter notebook

```
!pip install COVID19Py
```

Here is the Command:

```
Collecting COVID19Py

    Using cached COVID19Py-0.3.0.tar.gz (4.9 kB)

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'e:\anaconda3\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\RENSHA~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8p0iwje4\\COVID19Py\\setup.py'"'"'; 
__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\RENSHA~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8p0iwje4\\COVID19Py\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\RENSHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-aru6cxyv'
     cwd: C:\Users\RENSHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8p0iwje4\COVID19Py\

Complete output (5 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\RENSHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8p0iwje4\COVID19Py\setup.py", line 4, in <module>
    long_description = fh.read()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0xa8 in position 4010: illegal multibyte sequence
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have already update `python -m pip install --upgrade setuptools`

and `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

But it doesn't work.

---

WORK ENVIRONMENT:

Windows 10

Comment: It looks like your system has a default encoding of 'gbk'. The setup.py in COVID19Py is trying to read a utf-8 encoded text file, but they didn't specify encoding='utf-8' so it's using the system default. Most people's system is set up with 'utf-8' as the default so it works for them. This is a bug in the COVID19Py package, unfortunately I'm not sure what a good workaround is.

Comment: I went ahead and opened a PR on COVID19Py since it's a trivial change:

https://github.com/Kamaropoulos/COVID19Py/pull/18

Comment: Thanks a lot. So, do I need to wait Kamaropoulos to change this file and then to install the covid19py? Or do I have some other ways to install this package now?

Comment: In the meantime you could checkout the git repository, modify setup.py yourself and install from local. Or you can install from my git repo:

`pip install git+https://github.com/jbchouinard/COVID19Py.git@master`

But you should switch back to the official package at some point cause I will not be updating this.